# Change background makes its labels disappear

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I want to build an app where you can change the background image by clicking a button. First, to put a background to my frame, I created the image as a label and then sub-classed every other label to the background label. Now when you click the button "Change Background", it changes the background. However, all the labels disappear. Buttons only appear when you hover over them by the cursor. Labels never appear!
My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to fix it?

Here is a simple code to reproduce the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        
        self.controlFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=900, height=600)
        self.controlFrame.pack_propagate(0)   # Prevents resizing
        self.controlFrame.pack()
        
        
        
        img = Image.open('images/outside.jpg').resize((900, 600))
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)        
        self.background_label = tk.Label(self.controlFrame, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.configure(image = self.background_image)
        self.background_label.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
        
        
        
        self.changeButton = tk.Button(self.background_label, text="Change Background", 
                                    command = self.changeBK)
        self.changeButton.place(x=400, y=300)
        
        self.someButton = tk.Button(self.background_label, text="Some Button")                                    
        self.someButton.place(x=400, y=100)
        
        self.someOtherButton = tk.Button(self.background_label, text="Some Other Button")
        self.someOtherButton.place(x=400, y=450)
        
        self.userMessage = tk.Label(self.background_label, text="Label", height = 3 , width= 14, bg="white")
        self.userMessage.place(x=400, y= 200)
        
    def changeBK(self):
        img = Image.open('images/muddyPath.jpg').resize((900, 600))
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.background_label.configure(image = self.background_image)

def main():
    win = tk.Tk()                           # Create a window
    win.title("Using Multiple Layouts")     # Set window title
    win.geometry("900x600")                 # Set window size
    win.resizable(False, False)             # Both x and y dimensions ...

    # Create the GUI as a Frame
    # and attach it to the window ...
    myApp = App(win)

    # Call the GUI mainloop ...
    win.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A `Label` is not designed as a container for other widgets.  Use `self.controlFrame` as the parent for those buttons and label instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I want to have `self.background_image` as a background to the frame and I don't know other ways to do so other than putting everything in this image label.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in my comment?

Comment: @acw1668 Already did, yes. If  `self.controlFrame` is the parent for both the buttons and the image, then I can not, to my knowledge, have the image _behind_ the buttons as I want.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine if just changing the parent of the buttons and label from `self.background_label` to `self.controlFrame`.

Comment: @acw1668 Now I feel stupid. What I tried had the image label packed in `changeBK` instead of modifying the image option of it. Thank you very much for your help! and sorry for my mistake. Do you think I should delete this question now?